# I am trying to print some list containing '\t' and '\n' . But as python is not printing it because it is thinking it as a special character

Tags: python, list

I have a  delim list . Now I want to print every element in delim list. But print funtion in python is printing everything except character like '\t' , '\n'. I know it is usual . But can I print this like normal characters or strings.

```
delim=['\t','\n',',',';','(',')','{','}','[',']','#','<','>']

for c in delim:
        print c
```

It is giving output :
it is printing all the list skipping \t and \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change them to raw string literals by prefixing a `r`:

```
>>> print '\n'

>>> print r'\n'
\n
```

For your example this would mean:

```
delim=[r'\t',r'\n',',',';','(',')','{','}','[',']','#','<','>']

for c in delim:
    print c
```

Comment: Thank you . That worked pretty well .

Comment: If @AtifImam wants to use these delimeters in a split later this solution will fail, because `str.split(r'\n')` will look for occurences of a backslash followed by `n` and not a newline. Same for `r'\t'`

Comment: You're right, it really depends on what he plans to do with it.

Comment: I am learning many interesting things tody ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print them differently use `repr`

```
for c in delim:
    print repr(c)
```

Note: You will also see additional `'` at the beginning and end of each string.

Comment: Thanks. this also worked .